# Suggestion for automatic alignment of large equations

Tags: align, page-breaking

I have copied some large equations from Maple into LaTeX. Unfortunately, they are too big to fit on one page. Using `align` environment or similar environments will take many hours to align all the equations, with a high likelihood of errors.

Furthermore, for different document classes such as `onecolumn` or `twocolumn` and different format setting, this laborious process must be repeated. Alignment using `dmath` is not nice from right and when the equations exceed one page it makes an error.

Can anyone suggest a way on a nice automatic alignment of these large equations?

Here is one of my big equations:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}
\begin{dmath}


    0.02925000000\, \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\theta \left( t
 \right)  \right) \sin \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right) 
 \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) \sin
 \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right) + 0.02925000000\, \left( {
\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\theta \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( 
\theta \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}
\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( \alpha \left( t \right) 
 \right) - 0.01348859649\, \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}W \left( t
 \right)  \right) ^{2}\cos \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right) 
\cos \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right) - 0.01348859649\, \left( 
{\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}W \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}\sin \left( 
\theta \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( \alpha \left( t \right) 
 \right) - 0.1000000000\, \left( - 0.7341739112\,W \left( t \right) {
\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}W \left( t \right) - 0.5537021440\,W \left( t
 \right) {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\theta \left( t \right) +
 0.5537021440\,W \left( t \right) {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\alpha
 \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( -{\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\theta
 \left( t \right) +{\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\alpha \left( t \right) 
 \right) \sin \left( -\theta \left( t \right) +\alpha \left( t
 \right)  \right) + 0.1000000000\, \left(  \left(  0.3670869556\,
 \left( W \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}- 0.5000000000 \right) {\frac 
{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\alpha \left( t \right) + \left( - 0.3670869556\,
 \left( W \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}+ 0.5000000000 \right) {\frac 
{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\theta \left( t \right) + 0.5537021440\,{\frac 
{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}W \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( -{\frac {\rm d}{
{\rm d}t}}\theta \left( t \right) +{\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\alpha
 \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( -\theta \left( t \right) +
\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) - 0.1468347822\, \left( - \left( {
\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\theta \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( 
\theta \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( \alpha \left( t \right) 
 \right) -\cos \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac 
{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( \alpha
 \left( t \right)  \right) + \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\theta
 \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( \theta \left( t \right) 
 \right) \sin \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right) +\sin \left( 
\theta \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}
\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( \alpha \left( t \right) 
 \right)  \right) W \left( t \right) {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}W
 \left( t \right) - 0.07341739112\, \left( \cos \left( \theta \left( t
 \right)  \right) \cos \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right) +\sin
 \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( \alpha \left( t
 \right)  \right)  \right) W \left( t \right) {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{
{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}W \left( t \right) - 0.01462500000\, \left( {\frac {
{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}\theta \left( t \right)  \right) \sin
 \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( \alpha \left( t
 \right)  \right) - 0.01462500000\,\cos \left( \theta \left( t
 \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}\alpha
 \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( \alpha \left( t \right) 
 \right) + 0.01462500000\, \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}
}\theta \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( \theta \left( t \right) 
 \right) \sin \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right) + 0.01462500000
\,\sin \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {{\rm d}
^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( 
\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) - 0.01218058698\, \left( {\frac {
{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}W \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( 
\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( \theta \left( t \right) 
 \right) + 0.01218058698\, \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}
}W \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( \theta \left( t \right) 
 \right) \sin \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right) - 0.02697719305
\,W \left( t \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\theta \left( t
 \right)  \right) \cos \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right) \sin
 \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right) {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}W
 \left( t \right) - 0.01348859656\, \left( W \left( t \right) 
 \right) ^{2} \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\theta \left( t \right) 
 \right) \cos \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac 
{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( \alpha
 \left( t \right)  \right) - 0.02697719305\,W \left( t \right) \sin
 \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{
{\rm d}t}}\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( \alpha \left( t
 \right)  \right) {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}W \left( t \right) +
 0.02697719305\,W \left( t \right) \cos \left( \theta \left( t
 \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\alpha \left( t
 \right)  \right) \sin \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right) {\frac 
{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}W \left( t \right) - 0.01348859656\, \left( W
 \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2} \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\theta
 \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( \theta \left( t \right) 
 \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\alpha \left( t \right) 
 \right) \sin \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right) + 0.02436117396
\,W \left( t \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\theta \left( t
 \right)  \right) \cos \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right) 
 \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) \sin
 \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right) - 0.02436117396\,W \left( t
 \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\theta \left( t \right) 
 \right) \sin \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( 
\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\alpha
 \left( t \right) - 0.01218058698\,W \left( t \right)  \left( {\frac {
{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}\theta \left( t \right)  \right) \sin
 \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( \alpha \left( t
 \right)  \right) + 0.01218058698\,W \left( t \right) \sin \left( 
\theta \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{
t}^{2}}}\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( \alpha \left( t
 \right)  \right) - 0.01218058698\,W \left( t \right)  \left( {\frac {
{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}\theta \left( t \right)  \right) \cos
 \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( \alpha \left( t
 \right)  \right) + 0.01218058698\,W \left( t \right) \cos \left( 
\theta \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( \alpha \left( t \right) 
 \right) {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}\alpha \left( t \right) 
- 0.01348859649\,W \left( t \right)  \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{
{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}W \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( \theta \left( 
t \right)  \right) \cos \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right) -
 0.01348859649\,W \left( t \right)  \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{
{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}W \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( \theta \left( 
t \right)  \right) \sin \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right) +
 0.006744298281\, \left( W \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2} \left( {
\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}\theta \left( t \right)  \right) 
\sin \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( \alpha
 \left( t \right)  \right) - 0.006744298281\, \left( W \left( t
 \right)  \right) ^{2}\sin \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right) 
 \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}\alpha \left( t \right) 
 \right) \cos \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right) - 0.006744298281
\, \left( W \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2} \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}
{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}\theta \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( \theta
 \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( \alpha \left( t \right) 
 \right) + 0.006744298281\, \left( W \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}
\cos \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{
2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( 
\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) - 0.02436117396\, \left( {\frac 
{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}W \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{
{\rm d}t}}\theta \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( \theta \left( t
 \right)  \right) \sin \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right) +
 0.01218058698\,W \left( t \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}
\theta \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}\sin \left( \theta \left( t
 \right)  \right) \cos \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right) -
 0.02436117396\, \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}W \left( t \right) 
 \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\theta \left( t \right) 
 \right) \cos \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( 
\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) + 0.006744298281\, \left( W \left( t
 \right)  \right) ^{2} \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\theta \left( t
 \right)  \right) ^{2}\cos \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right) 
\cos \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right) + 0.02436117396\, \left( 
{\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}W \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( 
\theta \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}
\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( \alpha \left( t \right) 
 \right) - 0.01218058698\,W \left( t \right) \cos \left( \theta
 \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\alpha
 \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}\sin \left( \alpha \left( t \right) 
 \right) + 0.02436117396\, \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}W \left( t
 \right)  \right) \cos \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right) \cos
 \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right) {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}
\alpha \left( t \right) + 0.1000000000\, \left( - \left( {\frac {
{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}\theta \left( t \right)  \right) \sin
 \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( \alpha \left( t
 \right)  \right) - \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\theta \left( t
 \right)  \right) ^{2}\cos \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right) 
\cos \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right) +2\, \left( {\frac 
{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\theta \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( \theta
 \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\alpha
 \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( \alpha \left( t \right) 
 \right) -\cos \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac 
{{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) \sin
 \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right) -\cos \left( \theta \left( t
 \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\alpha \left( t
 \right)  \right) ^{2}\cos \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right) +
 \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}\theta \left( t \right) 
 \right) \cos \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( 
\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) - \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}
\theta \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}\sin \left( \theta \left( t
 \right)  \right) \sin \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right) +2\,
 \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\theta \left( t \right)  \right) \cos
 \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{
{\rm d}t}}\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( \alpha \left( t
 \right)  \right) +\sin \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right) 
 \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}\alpha \left( t \right) 
 \right) \cos \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right) -\sin \left( 
\theta \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}
\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}\sin \left( \alpha \left( t
 \right)  \right)  \right)  \left(  0.5- 0.3670869556\, \left( W
 \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2} \right) + 0.1000000000\, \left( 
 0.7341739112\,W \left( t \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}W
 \left( t \right)  \right) {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\alpha \left( t
 \right) + \left(  0.3670869556\, \left( W \left( t \right)  \right) ^
{2}- 0.5000000000 \right) {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}\alpha
 \left( t \right) - 0.7341739112\,W \left( t \right)  \left( {\frac 
{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}W \left( t \right)  \right) {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}
}\theta \left( t \right) + \left( - 0.3670869556\, \left( W \left( t
 \right)  \right) ^{2}+ 0.5000000000 \right) {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{
{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}\theta \left( t \right) + 0.5537021440\,{\frac {
{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}W \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( -
\theta \left( t \right) +\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) +
 0.05537021439\, \left( \cos \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right) 
\sin \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right) -\sin \left( \theta
 \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( \alpha \left( t \right) 
 \right)  \right) {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}W \left( t
 \right) + 0.1000000000\, \left( - 0.7341739112\, \left( {\frac 
{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}W \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}- 0.7341739112\,W
 \left( t \right) {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}W \left( t
 \right) - 0.5537021440\, \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\theta
 \left( t \right)  \right) {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}W \left( t
 \right) - 0.5537021440\,W \left( t \right) {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{
{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}\theta \left( t \right) + 0.5537021440\, \left( {
\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) {\frac 
{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}W \left( t \right) + 0.5537021440\,W \left( t
 \right) {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}\alpha \left( t \right) 
 \right) \cos \left( -\theta \left( t \right) +\alpha \left( t
 \right)  \right) + 0.05537021439\, \left( - \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2
}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}\theta \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( \theta
 \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( \alpha \left( t \right) 
 \right) - \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\theta \left( t \right) 
 \right) ^{2}\cos \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( 
\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) -2\, \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}
\theta \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( \theta \left( t \right) 
 \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\alpha \left( t \right) 
 \right) \cos \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right) +\cos \left( 
\theta \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{
t}^{2}}}\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( \alpha \left( t
 \right)  \right) -\cos \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right) 
 \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}
\sin \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right) - \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^
{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}\theta \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( 
\theta \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( \alpha \left( t \right) 
 \right) + \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\theta \left( t \right) 
 \right) ^{2}\sin \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( 
\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) +2\, \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}
\theta \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( \theta \left( t \right) 
 \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\alpha \left( t \right) 
 \right) \sin \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right) +\sin \left( 
\theta \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{
t}^{2}}}\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( \alpha \left( t
 \right)  \right) +\sin \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right) 
 \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}
\cos \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right)  \right) W \left( t
 \right) 
 \end{dmath}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please break down your code to the minimal required amount to show your problem.

Comment: It was broke down to the minimal amount.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would simply use inline math here and disable all the spurious left and right

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}\let\left\relax\let\right\relax
$
 - 0.01348859649\, \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}W \left( t \right) 
\right) ^{2}\sin \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( 
\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) - 0.01348859649\, \left( {\frac 
{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}W \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}\cos \left( \theta
 \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( \alpha \left( t \right) 
 \right) + 0.006744298252\, \left( W \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}
\cos \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{
{\rm d}t}}\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}\cos \left( \alpha
 \left( t \right)  \right) + 0.006744298281\, \left( W \left( t
 \right)  \right) ^{2} \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\theta \left( t
 \right)  \right) ^{2}\cos \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right) 
\cos \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right) + 0.01218058698\,W
 \left( t \right) \sin \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right) 
 \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}
\cos \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right) - 0.01462500000\, \left( 
{\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\theta \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}\cos
 \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( \alpha \left( t
 \right)  \right) - 0.01462500000\,\cos \left( \theta \left( t
 \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\alpha \left( t
 \right)  \right) ^{2}\cos \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right) -
 0.1000000000\, \left( - 0.7341739112\,W \left( t \right) {\frac 
{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}W \left( t \right) - 0.5537021440\,W \left( t
 \right) {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\theta \left( t \right) +
 0.5537021440\,W \left( t \right) {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\alpha
 \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( -{\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\theta
 \left( t \right) +{\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\alpha \left( t \right) 
 \right) \sin \left( -\theta \left( t \right) +\alpha \left( t
 \right)  \right) - 0.1468347822\, \left( - \left( {\frac {\rm d}{
{\rm d}t}}\theta \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( \theta \left( t
 \right)  \right) \cos \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right) -\cos
 \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{
{\rm d}t}}\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( \alpha \left( t
 \right)  \right) + \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\theta \left( t
 \right)  \right) \cos \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right) \sin
 \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right) +\sin \left( \theta \left( t
 \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\alpha \left( t
 \right)  \right) \cos \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right) 
 \right) W \left( t \right) {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}W \left( t
 \right) + 0.1000000000\, \left(  \left(  0.3670869556\, \left( W
 \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}- 0.5000000000 \right) {\frac {\rm d}{
{\rm d}t}}\alpha \left( t \right) + \left( - 0.3670869556\, \left( W
 \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}+ 0.5000000000 \right) {\frac {\rm d}{
{\rm d}t}}\theta \left( t \right) + 0.5537021440\,{\frac {\rm d}{
{\rm d}t}}W \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( -{\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t
}}\theta \left( t \right) +{\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\alpha \left( t
 \right)  \right) \cos \left( -\theta \left( t \right) +\alpha \left( 
t \right)  \right) - 0.01218058698\,W \left( t \right)  \left( {\frac 
{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\theta \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}\cos \left( 
\theta \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( \alpha \left( t \right) 
 \right) + 0.1107404288\, \left( - \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}
\theta \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( \theta \left( t \right) 
 \right) \sin \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right) +\cos \left( 
\theta \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}
\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( \alpha \left( t \right) 
 \right) - \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\theta \left( t \right) 
 \right) \cos \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( 
\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) +\sin \left( \theta \left( t \right) 
 \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\alpha \left( t \right) 
 \right) \sin \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right)  \right) {\frac 
{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}W \left( t \right) - 0.07341739112\, \left( \cos
 \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( \alpha \left( t
 \right)  \right) +\sin \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right) \sin
 \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac 
{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}W \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}+ 2.258500000\,{
\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}x \left( t \right) + 0.02436117396
\, \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}W \left( t \right)  \right) \cos
 \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( \alpha \left( t
 \right)  \right) {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\alpha \left( t \right) +
 0.006744298281\, \left( W \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2} \left( {
\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\theta \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}\sin
 \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( \alpha \left( t
 \right)  \right) + 0.006744298252\, \left( W \left( t \right) 
 \right) ^{2}\sin \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {
\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}\sin
 \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right) + 0.02925000000\, \left( {
\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\theta \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( 
\theta \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}
\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( \alpha \left( t \right) 
 \right) + 0.02925000000\, \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\theta
 \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( \theta \left( t \right) 
 \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\alpha \left( t \right) 
 \right) \sin \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right) - 0.01218058698
\,W \left( t \right) \cos \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right) 
 \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}
\sin \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right) + 0.02436117396\, \left( 
{\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}W \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( 
\theta \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}
\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( \alpha \left( t \right) 
 \right) + 0.05537021439\, \left( \cos \left( \theta \left( t \right) 
 \right) \sin \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right) -\cos \left( 
\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( \theta \left( t \right) 
 \right)  \right) {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}W \left( t
 \right) + 0.1000000000\, \left( - 0.7341739112\, \left( {\frac 
{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}W \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}- 0.7341739112\,W
 \left( t \right) {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}W \left( t
 \right) - 0.5537021440\, \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}W \left( t
 \right)  \right) {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\theta \left( t \right) -
 0.5537021440\,W \left( t \right) {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}
}\theta \left( t \right) + 0.5537021440\, \left( {\frac {\rm d}{
{\rm d}t}}\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}W
 \left( t \right) + 0.5537021440\,W \left( t \right) {\frac {{\rm d}^{
2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( -
\theta \left( t \right) +\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) +
 0.1000000000\, \left( - \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}
\theta \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( \theta \left( t \right) 
 \right) \cos \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right) - \left( {\frac 
{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\theta \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}\cos \left( 
\theta \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( \alpha \left( t \right) 
 \right) +2\, \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\theta \left( t \right) 
 \right) \sin \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac 
{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( \alpha
 \left( t \right)  \right) -\cos \left( \theta \left( t \right) 
 \right)  \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}\alpha \left( t
 \right)  \right) \sin \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right) -\cos
 \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{
{\rm d}t}}\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}\cos \left( \alpha
 \left( t \right)  \right) + \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2
}}}\theta \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( \theta \left( t
 \right)  \right) \sin \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right) -
 \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\theta \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}
\sin \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( \alpha
 \left( t \right)  \right) +2\, \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\theta
 \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( \theta \left( t \right) 
 \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\alpha \left( t \right) 
 \right) \cos \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right) +\sin \left( 
\theta \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{
t}^{2}}}\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( \alpha \left( t
 \right)  \right) -\sin \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right) 
 \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}
\sin \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right)  \right)  \left(  0.5-
 0.3670869556\, \left( W \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2} \right) +
 0.05537021439\, \left( - \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}
\theta \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( \theta \left( t \right) 
 \right) \sin \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right) - \left( {\frac 
{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\theta \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}\cos \left( 
\theta \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( \alpha \left( t \right) 
 \right) -2\, \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\theta \left( t \right) 
 \right) \sin \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac 
{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( \alpha
 \left( t \right)  \right) +\cos \left( \theta \left( t \right) 
 \right)  \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}\alpha \left( t
 \right)  \right) \cos \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right) -\cos
 \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{
{\rm d}t}}\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}\sin \left( \alpha
 \left( t \right)  \right) - \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2
}}}\theta \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( \theta \left( t
 \right)  \right) \cos \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right) +
 \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\theta \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}
\sin \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( \alpha
 \left( t \right)  \right) +2\, \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\theta
 \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( \theta \left( t \right) 
 \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\alpha \left( t \right) 
 \right) \sin \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right) +\sin \left( 
\theta \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{
t}^{2}}}\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( \alpha \left( t
 \right)  \right) +\sin \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right) 
 \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}
\cos \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right)  \right) W \left( t
 \right) + 0.1000000000\, \left(  0.7341739112\,W \left( t \right) 
 \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}W \left( t \right)  \right) {\frac 
{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\alpha \left( t \right) + \left(  0.3670869556\,
 \left( W \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}- 0.5000000000 \right) {\frac 
{{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}\alpha \left( t \right) - 0.7341739112\,
W \left( t \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}W \left( t
 \right)  \right) {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\theta \left( t \right) +
 \left( - 0.3670869556\, \left( W \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}+
 0.5000000000 \right) {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}\theta
 \left( t \right) + 0.5537021440\,{\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}
}W \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( -\theta \left( t \right) +
\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) - 0.02436117396\, \left( {\frac 
{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}W \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{
{\rm d}t}}\theta \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( \theta \left( t
 \right)  \right) \sin \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right) -
 0.02436117396\, \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}W \left( t \right) 
 \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\theta \left( t \right) 
 \right) \cos \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( 
\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) + 0.01218058698\,W \left( t \right) 
 \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\theta \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}
\sin \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( \alpha
 \left( t \right)  \right) + 0.02436117396\,W \left( t \right) 
 \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\theta \left( t \right)  \right) \cos
 \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{
{\rm d}t}}\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( \alpha \left( t
 \right)  \right) + 0.02697719305\,W \left( t \right)  \left( {\frac 
{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\theta \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( \theta
 \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( \alpha \left( t \right) 
 \right) {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}W \left( t \right) - 0.02436117396\,
W \left( t \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\theta \left( t
 \right)  \right) \sin \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right) \cos
 \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right) {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}
\alpha \left( t \right) - 0.02697719299\,W \left( t \right) \sin
 \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{
{\rm d}t}}\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( \alpha \left( t
 \right)  \right) {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}W \left( t \right) -
 0.01348859653\, \left( W \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2} \left( {
\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\theta \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( 
\theta \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}
\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( \alpha \left( t \right) 
 \right) - 0.02697719305\,W \left( t \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{
{\rm d}t}}\theta \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( \theta \left( t
 \right)  \right) \sin \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right) {\frac 
{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}W \left( t \right) + 0.02697719299\,W \left( t
 \right) \cos \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac 
{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( \alpha
 \left( t \right)  \right) {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}W \left( t
 \right) - 0.01348859653\, \left( W \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}
 \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\theta \left( t \right)  \right) \sin
 \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{
{\rm d}t}}\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( \alpha \left( t
 \right)  \right) - 0.01462500000\,\sin \left( \theta \left( t
 \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\alpha \left( t
 \right)  \right) ^{2}\sin \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right) -
 0.01462500000\, \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}\theta \left( t
 \right)  \right) ^{2}\sin \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right) 
\sin \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right) + 0.006744298281\,
 \left( W \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2} \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{
{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}\theta \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( \theta
 \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( \alpha \left( t \right) 
 \right) + 0.01218058698\,W \left( t \right) \sin \left( \theta
 \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}
}}\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( \alpha \left( t
 \right)  \right) - 0.01348859649\,W \left( t \right) \cos \left( 
\theta \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( \alpha \left( t \right) 
 \right) {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}W \left( t \right) -
 0.01348859649\,W \left( t \right) \sin \left( \theta \left( t
 \right)  \right) \sin \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right) {\frac 
{{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}W \left( t \right) + 0.01218058698\,W
 \left( t \right) \cos \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right) \cos
 \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right) {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{
t}^{2}}}\alpha \left( t \right) - 0.006744298252\, \left( W \left( t
 \right)  \right) ^{2}\sin \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right) 
 \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}\alpha \left( t \right) 
 \right) \cos \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right) - 0.006744298281
\, \left( W \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2} \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}
{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}\theta \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( \theta
 \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( \alpha \left( t \right) 
 \right) - 0.01218058698\,W \left( t \right)  \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{
2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}\theta \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( 
\theta \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( \alpha \left( t \right) 
 \right) + 0.006744298252\, \left( W \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}
\cos \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{
2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( 
\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) - 0.01218058698\,W \left( t \right) 
 \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}\theta \left( t \right) 
 \right) \cos \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( 
\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) + 0.01218058698\,\cos \left( \theta
 \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( \alpha \left( t \right) 
 \right) {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}W \left( t \right) -
 0.01218058698\,\cos \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right) \sin
 \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right) {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{
t}^{2}}}W \left( t \right) - 0.07341739112\, \left( \cos \left( \theta
 \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( \alpha \left( t \right) 
 \right) +\sin \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( 
\alpha \left( t \right)  \right)  \right) W \left( t \right) {\frac {
{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}W \left( t \right) - 0.01462500000\,
 \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}\theta \left( t \right) 
 \right) \sin \left( \theta \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( 
\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) - 0.01462500000\,\cos \left( \theta
 \left( t \right)  \right)  \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}
}}\alpha \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( \alpha \left( t
 \right)  \right) + 0.01462500000\, \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{
{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}\theta \left( t \right)  \right) \cos \left( \theta
 \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( \alpha \left( t \right) 
 \right) + 0.01462500000\,\sin \left( \theta \left( t \right) 
 \right)  \left( {\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}\alpha \left( t
 \right)  \right) \cos \left( \alpha \left( t \right)  \right)
$
\end{flushleft}

 \end{document}
```