# Write huge equation (width 8 meters)

Tags: equations

[bigequation.tex](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xuwq8f10ueokk9b/Untitled.tex?dl=0)

I'm desperately trying to type this huge equation in an A4 page.

Any reasonable solution would be ok (including splitting the equation). The problem is that the total width is 800cm. Hence this would require more than 20 lines for a single equation (considering A4 width is 29.7cm).

Comment: where are you publishing this? International billboard of mathematics?

Comment: You can copy and paste your document here.   The web site you are using requires a logon.

Comment: This is obviously a joke, isn't it?

Comment: I know it does not make sense to type it but I have to do it. @egreg

Comment: Well, you're asking to manage a formula built up in the most awful way, 80K long. No, thanks.

Comment: It's outrageous but still a valid question. Please stop voting to close everything.

Comment: 800cm is more than `\maxdimen` (about 575.75 cm). So it is greater than the maximum width.

Comment: @percusse I pondered before voting to close. It's not a valid question, for several reasons.

Comment: @egreg such as?

Comment: @percusse No research, no attempt, just preposterous code produced by a dumb machine. Do it for me.

Comment: @egreg I've tried you can't paste (89k characters) it but includes a valid MWE. Dumb machine who knows? And definitely not do it for me.

Comment: @egreg Maybe it's time for a lipsum package that spits out random math?

Comment: @percusse "lipsum for math" already exists. It's called "mathematica".

Comment: @alephzero a humble symbolic effort :)

Comment: it is easy to allow linebreaking in sqrt and frac, but the hard part is `{...}^2`   do you need to use exactly that input or could such things be marked up as (say) `\power{...}{2}`  which would allow a suitable breakable version to be defined.

Comment: This is similar to this question, but harder because of the spurious brace groups in the input which prevent line breaking https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/358072/suggestion-for-automatic-alignment-of-large-equations/358073#358073

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The latex input is obtained from Matlab. My idea was to print that output directly since that equation is just one out of a list of similar equations.

Comment: Just for curiosity, could you explain to us the meaning of such a monster?

Comment: @MarcelloFiducioso You should never ever and ever use matlab latex output. There is simply no excuse. You don't use it. Just forget it exists.

Comment: @MarcelloFiducioso: Please consider accepting one of the two given answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following (technically) works with your dropbox-file. I just excluded your formula from the example. 
As https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/9057/schweinebacke mentioned your formula is bigger than the maximum width so you need to introduce line breaks. It is quite easy to find the spots with syntax highlighting.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[paperwidth=16383.99999pt,paperheight=100cm,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
1=1\forall 1 \\\textup{Your formula here}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Your might try `gather` instead of `align` in case you prefer a centered alignment.

Here is an image of the beauty:
[image]

**So if anyone knows how to extend `\maxdimen`, this would be welcomed.** Compare [What's the absolute largest paper size permissible with pdflatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/420/whats-the-absolute-largest-paper-size-permissible-with-pdflatex#430). 
Note 16383.99999pt*2.54/72.27*cm/pt≈5.75831741726858m.

Comment: Can you include the result screenshot so that it's not taken as a tongue-in-cheek answer?

Comment: @percusse Done. But I needed to reduce the resolution.

Comment: No worries. It's probably not meant for reading anyways

Comment: Thank you for your help. To be honest I do not succeed with your code but I obtained a similar result using:
\newcommand*{\Scale}[2][4]{\scalebox{#1}{$#2$}}%
\newcommand*{\Resize}[2]{\resizebox{#1}{!}{$#2$}}%
\begin{equation}
\Scale[0.02]{equation here}
\end{equation}

Comment: If I scroll all the way to the right, it looks cut-off.

Comment: @CampanIgnis A nice wallpaper :)

Comment: `\maxdimen` is not a PDF limit but a TeX limit.

Comment: @Schweinebacke So is there a way to extend it?

Comment: No. Not without changing TeX itself. And the result wouldn't be TeX. See: [What's the absolute largest paper size permissible with pdflatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/420/whats-the-absolute-largest-paper-size-permissible-with-pdflatex)

Comment: @Schweinebacke Do they not refer to a maximum size of approximately 508cm in PDF 1.6?

Comment: In PDF 1.5. From AFAIK PDF 1.6 you can change the unit size. I've never testes, how to do so using `pdftex`. But I think this is theory only. Because it doesn't really matter: You cannot have paper or text area width of 800cm with TeX.

Comment: I hoped that LuaTeX would be more flexible here.

Comment: @CampanIgnis It would not longer count as TeX. By definition.

Comment: @cfr That is what Schweinebacke already said.

Answer (score 11):

[image]

The hardest part is getting rid of the spurious `{}` groups, without that you would just need simple inline definitions as in

[Suggestion for automatic alignment of large equations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/358072/suggestion-for-automatic-alignment-of-large-equations/358073#358073)

Use `$\z ... \zstop $` not `begin{equation}...\end{equation}` otherwise the math is unchanged.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
%\usepackage[paperwidth=500cm,paperheight=21cm,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\addtolength\textwidth{6cm}
\addtolength\oddsidemargin{-3cm}
\showboxbreadth10000
\showboxdepth10000
\begin{document}
\let\left\relax
\let\right\relax
\def\sqrt#1{(#1)^{{1\over2}}% image uses bad version: \def\sqrt#1{1/(#1)}
\def\frac#1#2{(#1)/(#2)}
\def\mathrm#1{\begingroup\fam0 #1\endgroup}
\let\!\relax% they should never have been there
\def\z#1{%
\ifx\frac#1\let\next\ztwo
\else\ifx\sqrt#1\let\next\zone
\else\ifx\mathrm#1\let\next\zone
\else\ifx^#1\let\next\zone
\else\ifx_#1\let\next\zone
\else\ifx\dot#1\let\next\zone
\else\let\next\znone
\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi
\next{#1}}
\def\ztwo#1#2#3{#1{\z#2\zstop}{\z#3\zstop}\z}
\def\zone#1#2{#1{\z#2\zstop}\z}
\def\znone#1{\zonex#1}
\def\zonex#1{#1\z}
\def\zstop#1{}
\begin{center}
$\z
 \frac{...}{...}
....
\frac{...}170}
\zstop$
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

Comment: The square root is not the reciprocal.

Comment: @egreg minor details:-) `\def\sqrt#1{(#1)^{{1\over2}}`

Comment: Not that anybody would notice. `;-)`