# How can I do automatic line breaks in LaTeX math mode?

Tags: math-mode, align, line-breaking

i have a Latex document with some very long equatations inside an `align*` element. They overflow the page width. My question is: How can I tell Latex to automatically insert linebreaks when the lines reach the end of the page? Or do I have to manually add the linebreaks?

My code is like this:

```
\begin{align*}
a_1 = someverylongequatationsheeesh + 435734 +345345345345 +345346456456 +456456456456
...
\end{align*}
```

I tried inserting `\allowbreak` about everywhere, but it didn't work. Also putting the equatations inside a `split` element didn't work.

Comment: Hi, welcome! There is a package: [breqn](https://ctan.org/pkg/breqn?lang=en), but *personally*, I would manually split the equation --- semantics are *really* difficult to get automatically.

Comment: Probably https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3782/how-can-i-split-an-equation-over-two-or-more-lines is a duplicate

Comment: breqn package or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/381002/write-huge-equation-width-8-meters/381066#381066