# How to automatically break fractions generated by Mathematica

Tags: line-breaking, fractions, breqn, wolfram-mathematica

I am looking for an automated way of presenting my Mathematica results in latex. My workflow at the moment is the following

1. I use `TeXForm[]` Mathematica function to generate a latex code from my expression
2. I copy the output to a latex document to `dmath` environment from `breqn` package, so I don't have to care about line breaking when expressions are lengthy.

Unfortunately, the method above doesn't work when fractions generated by Mathematica are too long (namely `dmath` doesn't have a built-in way to break `\frac{}{}`).

How could I deal with it?

The only way to break fractions I know, is `\splitfrac` but one has to put it by hand, which can be cumbersome for lengthy expressions.

I also tried to force Mathematica to generate latex code that uses a division symbol `/` instead of `\frac{}{}`, but I didn't manage to get a neatly working solution (with this style of output `dmath` would be sufficient).

What are the other possible solutions? Could you provide both Mathematica and latex snippets? What is your general workflow when presenting Mathematica results in latex?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code generating your issue! Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: probable duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/381002/write-huge-equation-width-8-meters/381066#381066

Comment: This is a great answer, thank you. However when using this solution I get the error "double superscript" at the end of each fraction:
<recently read> \mathsup 
                         
l.70 ...} \left(\sigma  p_{0}^{4}+1\right)\right)}
                                                   +\frac{i \delta m \left(1...
I treat `x^1^2' essentially like `x^1{}^2'.

<recently read> \mathsup 
                         
l.70 ...} \left(\sigma  p_{0}^{4}+1\right)\right)}
                                                  
I treat `x^1^2' essentially like `x^1{}^2'.