# Maple code imported into latex with no display breaks in equations

Tags: spacing, equations, page, maple2e, displaybreak

I had no problem getting maple code into latex, the issue I am having is that the equations are running off page. I was wondering if anyone had suggestions to fix this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{maplestd2e}
\def\emptyline{\vspace{12pt}}
\usepackage{lscape}
\newcommand{\maplebreak}{\hfill\break}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}
\DefineParaStyle{Maple Heading 1}
\DefineParaStyle{Maple Text Output}
\DefineParaStyle{Maple Dash Item}
\DefineParaStyle{Maple Bullet Item}
\DefineParaStyle{Maple Normal}
\DefineParaStyle{Maple Heading 4}
\DefineParaStyle{Maple Heading 3}
\DefineParaStyle{Maple Heading 2}
\DefineParaStyle{Maple Warning}
\DefineParaStyle{Maple Title}
\DefineParaStyle{Maple Error}
\DefineCharStyle{Maple Hyperlink}
\DefineCharStyle{Maple 2D Math}
\DefineCharStyle{Maple Maple Input}
\DefineCharStyle{Maple 2D Output}
\DefineCharStyle{Maple 2D Input}

\mapleinline{inert}{2d}{U := m[1]*m[2]/[(u[1]-u[2])^2+(v[1]-v[2])^2+(w[1]-w[2])^2]^(1/2)+m[1]*M[1]/[(u[1]+a*M[2]/M)^2+v[1]^2+w[1]^2]^(1/2)+m[1]*M[2]/[(u[1]-a*M[1]/M)^2+v[1]^2+w[1]^2]^(1/2)+m[2]*M[1]/[(u[2]+a*M[2]/M)^2+v[2]^2+w[2]^2]^(1/2)+m[2]*M[2]/[(u[2]-a*M[1]/M)^2+v[2]^2+w[2]^2]^(1/2); 1}{\[\displaystyle \]}

\mapleinline{inert}{2d}{U := m[1]*m[2]/[(u[1]-u[2])^2+(v[1]-v[2])^2+(w[1]-w[2])^2]^(1/2)+m[1]*M[1]/[(u[1]+a*M[2]/M)^2+v[1]^2+w[1]^2]^(1/2)+m[1]*M[2]/[(u[1]-a*M[1]/M)^2+v[1]^2+w[1]^2]^(1/2)+m[2]*M[1]/[(u[2]+a*M[2]/M)^2+v[2]^2+w[2]^2]^(1/2)+m[2]*M[2]/[(u[2]-a*M[1]/M)^2+v[2]^2+w[2]^2]^(1/2); 1}{\[\displaystyle \]}
\begin{maplegroup}
\mapleresult
\begin{maplelatex}
\mapleinline{inert}{2d}{m[1]*m[2]/sqrt([(u[1]-u[2])^2+(v[1]-v[2])^2+(w[1]-w[2])^2])+m[1]*M[1]/sqrt([(u[1]+a*M[2]/M)^2+v[1]^2+w[1]^2])+m[1]*M[2]/sqrt([(u[1]-a*M[1]/M)^2+v[1]^2+w[1]^2])+m[2]*M[1]/sqrt([(u[2]+a*M[2]/M)^2+v[2]^2+w[2]^2])+m[2]*M[2]/sqrt([(u[2]-a*M[1]/M)^2+v[2]^2+w[2]^2])}{\[\displaystyle {\frac {m_{{1}}m_{{2}}}{ \sqrt{[ \left( u_{{1}}-u_{{2}} \right) ^{2}+ \left( v_{{1}}-v_{{2}} \right) ^{2}+ \left( w_{{1}}-w_{{2}} \right) ^{2}\\
\mbox{}]}}}+m_{{1}}M_{{1}} \left(  \sqrt{[ \left( u_{{1}}+{\frac {aM_{{2}}}{M}} \right) ^{2}+{v_{{1}}}^{2}+{w_{{1}}}^{2}]} \right) ^{-1}+m_{{1}}M_{{2}} \left(  \sqrt{[ \left( u_{{1}}-{\frac {aM_{{1}}}{M}} \right) ^{2}+{v_{{1}}}^{2}+{w_{{1}}}^{2}]} \right) ^{-1}\\
\mbox{}+m_{{2}}M_{{1}} \left(  \sqrt{[ \left( u_{{2}}+{\frac {aM_{{2}}}{M}} \right) ^{2}+{v_{{2}}}^{2}+{w_{{2}}}^{2}]} \right) ^{-1}+m_{{2}}M_{{2}} \left(  \sqrt{[ \left( u_{{2}}-{\frac {aM_{{1}}}{M}} \right) ^{2}+{v_{{2}}}^{2}+{w_{{2}}}^{2}]} \right) ^{-1}\]}
\end{maplelatex}
\end{maplegroup}
\end{document}
```

This is a section of the code that I am using that was imported from Maple. Minus the fact that the other latex files needed to run it have not been included, it should run.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: `maplestd2e` doesn't seem to be a standard TeX file, so that's a pretty big "minus the fact" that keeps me from being able to see what you're talking about.

Comment: How would I share that file with the community? It is quite a bit larger then the code that I even posted above.

Comment: @NewbieMather: Perhaps consider [Pastebin](//pastebin.com).

Comment: The first hit with Google can be useful. Not sure it's the same copy as yours. But I don't think there is a provision for `\mapleinline` to break formulas across lines. The output is awful anyway.

Comment: I posted the code for it. Let me know if there is anything else needed

Comment: I did try Googling it first before coming here. I tried several different things but they weren't working. I even tried flipping to landscape to see if it would help, but it ended up give an even weirder pdf then the first. That being said I have cut out an enormous amount of latex for this post since it was just a massive file in the first place.

Comment: how come some of the square roots are marked up as `\sqrt`  but others are just as text `sqrt` which wil be set as a product of variables s q r t

Comment: tbh I have no idea. Like I said this was code that was imported from Maple. Even if I go in and change that by hand it still does not display in a way that is useful. If I could show you the PDF I would. But since this is my first post on this side of stack exchange it won't let me.

Comment: yes it will be all on one line, there are some posts on this site showing how to modify code from similar systems to allow line breaking (I'll find a link) but you need the inut tex to be at least slightly reasonable but this does not look that way. I suspect issues in teh original maple code, its output isn't normally that bad I think

Comment: see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/358073/1090

Comment: Awesome! Thank you