# Render Very large equation

Tags: equations, breqn

I have a very large equation that was autogenerated by a code and I want to render it.
I have tried using the `\usepackage[]{breqn}` but it is too large.
I will propably go more than one page. Is there any way to archieve this?
(I can't copy paste the equation here as an example, because its too long)

Comment: a 5-page equation https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/381066/1090

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle, for getting me on the right track this solution worked for me: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/358073/204320